# Problems in accessing values in json with Python '\n’

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm really stuck in a probably easy-to-solve problem.
my .json file looks like this:

```
{\n  \"keywords\": [\n    {\n      \"relevance\": 0.936156, \n
          \"text\": \"Montana\"\n    },
\n    {\n      \"relevance\": 0.878111, \n
  \"text\": \"English\"\n    },...
```

If I load it to Python and print it out in the console,
I don't have the '\n' and the '\’.
But no matter what I'm trying, I'm not getting the values.

```
data = json.loads(json_str)
```

Are somehow loading the file, but if I cannot access a certain value.

Do I have to preprocess the file in some way?

Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: \n is the syntax for a newline in a string

Comment: Does your json file start with a single quote followed by a double quote, like it does here? That means that `loads` will give you a string, not a dict. Where did this json data come from? Whatever is writing it is probably doing so incorrectly.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't have any quotes, just my fault.
Its a jsonfile I get as an output from a sentiment analysis.

That means I can't use this output?

Comment: Does not work just means nothing... Please show what gives `print(repr(json_str))` and describe how you try to access the value and what happens if you do.

Answer (score -1):

As is it a str object , you can add the following code for removing all the spacing characters from your data.

```
data = json.loads(json_str.replace("\n","").replace("\t","").replace(" ",""))
```

Comment: And then all the spaces disappear from your keys and values and your data is corrupt and needs to be recovered.

Comment: I have edited the code such that it does retain original str.
As the nature of data is numerical, thus this solution will not interfere with the data.